# find more information about the drive/partition ubuntu is installed on

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop alongside Windows 10. I had made an un-allocated partition of ~270GB on my Samsung 860ev0 500GB SSD for installed Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu successfully, in fact i am writing this question on Firefox on Ubuntu. But, when i check it on disk management on windows, that partition i had made is still un-allocated. Here is the result of "df" command of my terminal, results of which made no sense to me whatever.

[image]

Will you please help me figure out if I have installed Ubuntu on that partition!. And if I have not installed it on my SSd, will you please also point me to an article that shows how to install it on unallocated partition of my SSD and not on HDD.

FYI, I also have a 1 TB Western Digital HDD(NTFS formatted) in another slot of my laptop.

EDIT 1:
here is the screenshot of Gparted for my SSD. I presume this means I have installed both operating systems on my SSD. Correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

EDIT 2:

```
naveen@naveen-lap:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop1    7:1    0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop2    7:2    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop3    7:3    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop4    7:4    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop5    7:5    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
loop6    7:6    0 217.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop7    7:7    0  30.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9279
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   499M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0 205.2G  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   844M  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0 259.1G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
naveen@naveen-lap:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for naveen: 
Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVX-60J (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB  523MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      524MB   629MB  105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      629MB   646MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      646MB   221GB  220GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      221GB   499GB  278GB   ext4
 5      499GB   500GB  885MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag


naveen@naveen-lap:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ubuntu follows the `sdx#` format to identify physical volumes (disks) and partitions (divisions of disks):**

- `x` stands in for a specific physical volume represented by a letter (`a`, `b`, `c`...);
- `#`, is a partition of a volume `x` represented, in order, by number (`1`, `2`, `3`...)

Based on the information you provided, there is a Windows installation on `sdb4` and there is an Ubuntu installation on `sdb6`.
This tells you that **Windows and Ubuntu are on the same physical volume**.

Here is how I determined this:

On this [screenshot of `df`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f20zZ.png), it shows your root file system `/` mounted to `/dev/sdb6`.  You told us that you ran these commands from your installation so that means that your Ubuntu installation is unequivocally on `sdb6`

A typical Windows installation adds several partitions, so it is pretty easy to  spot Windows from these outputs:

- `sdb1` is Windows' "Recovery" partition.
- `sdb2` is the EFI system partition, which is needed to boot both UEFI operating systems.
- `sdb3` is the MSR "Microsoft Reserved" partition.
- `sdb4` ?? -- *clues: 200-220 GB (+/-), NTFS file system (a proprietary file system by Microsoft)*
- `sdb5` is only 500MB in capacity so Windows *can't* be there: Windows is way too big.
- `sdb6` - we already determined is Ubuntu.

There are no more partitions on `sdb` so this only leaves `sdb4` which has to be your Windows installation (What Windows will call `C:`)

As far as whether or not `sdb` is your SSD or some other device, you can usually deduce this from file sizes, and from knowing what was already on your device.

For example: Presumably, your pre-existing Windows installation in the ballpark *+/-* of 200GB was already on your SSD.  Since it is on `sdb4`, then your SSD is the physical volume `sdb`.  Since Ubuntu is on `sdb6`, which is on `sdb`, then **Ubuntu is on your SSD** as well.

You can also see the model identification as "Samsung SSD" along with the above partitions for `sdb` in the output of `sudo parted -l`.